# Sample Camera Functionality in IPhone Application

Tags: iphone, camera, simulator

Hai

Can any one suggest me how to work with camera functionality in iphone simulator?

Thanks
Basanth

Answer (score 1):

You can't test the iPhone camera APIs on the Simulator using current tools and frameworks from Apple.  You need to test on the device.